# Manually sorting in PHP

Tags: php, sorting, quick-sort

I had read about quicksort in some articles. Is this is a correct implementation of quicksort?

```
function quicksort() {
// Setup data to sort
$data = array();
for ($i=0; $i < 500; $i++) { 
    $data[] = rand(0, 515);
}

// Begin looping 
for ($x=0; $x < count($data); $x++) { 
    for ($y=$x; $y < count($data); $y++) {
        // Check to swap
        if ($data[$x] > $data[$y]) {
            // Snapshot
            $one = $data[$x];
            $two = $data[$y];

            // Swapping
            $data[$x] = $two;
            $data[$y] = $one;
        }
    }
}

return $data;

}

print_r(quicksort());
```

Comment: Are you after a review of your code, or simply for somebody to say this doesn't look like a quick sort?

Comment: This smells like bubble sort.

Comment: @forsvarir currently for reviewing my code ..

Comment: Looks like you want your code to be explained instead of reviewed. Please edit your question to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Type of sort

This is not [Quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort).  The Quicksort algorithm works by recursively dividing the data into two groups, one less than a pivot value and the other greater.  You have no pivot value here and do not work with subarrays.  So this can't be a Quicksort implementation.

This looks a bit like [Bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) which is another exchange-based sort.  But that's not it either.  In reality, this is [Selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort).

#### Separate concerns

> ```
> function quicksort() {
> // Setup data to sort
> $data = array();
> for ($i=0; $i < 500; $i++) { 
>     $data[] = rand(0, 515);
> }
> ```

No sorting method should create its own data.  This should be done outside the sorting routine.

```
function create_test_data($count, $minimum, $maximum) {
    $data = [];

    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) { 
        $data[] = rand($minimum, $maximum);
    }

    return $data;
}

function quicksort($data) {
```

This parameterizes the basic values rather than hardcoding them.  So you can use this same code for multiple tests.

The newer way to initialize an empty array is to use `[]`.

#### Avoid unnecessary work

> ```
> for ($x=0; $x < count($data); $x++) { 
>     for ($y=$x; $y < count($data); $y++) {
> ```

Not enough indent.

```
    for ($x = 0, $n = count($data); $x < $n; $x++) { 
        for ($y = $x + 1; $y < $n; $y++) {
```

At one point, `count` was an \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$ operation in PHP, so it is common to do it only once.

There is no point in comparing `$data[$x]` and `$data[$x]`.  So we can skip the first iteration of your original inner loop.

#### Don't use two steps to do one thing

> ```
>             // Snapshot
>             $one = $data[$x];
>             $two = $data[$y];
>
>             // Swapping
>             $data[$x] = $two;
>             $data[$y] = $one;
> ```

You don't need a `$two` variable.

```
                $temp = $data[$x];
                $data[$x] = $data[$y];
                $data[$y] = $temp;
```

The datum at `$y` can be moved to `$x` directly.

#### PHP supports Quicksort natively

If you just want sorted data, you don't need to write it.  You can just say

```
$data = create_test_data(500, 0, 515);
sort($data);
print_r($data);
```

The PHP [`sort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) function uses Quicksort.